# Clipping tiff image with a bounding box with GDAL in Java

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

Since GDAL 2.1 GDAL and OGR utilities can be used as library functions, so this task is incredibly simple now:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open('original.tif')
ds = gdal.Translate('new.tif', ds, projWin = [-75.3, 5.5, -73.5, 3.7])
ds = None
```

Is there a similar library in Java to replace gdal_translate.exe call?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. you can call the same using GDAL Java bindings.

Official documentation can be found at this [link](https://gdal.org/java/overview-summary.html)

For downloading it using maven you can find maven repo link [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gdal/gdal/2.1.0)

You can find details of translate function [here](https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/gdal.html#Translate-java.lang.String-org.gdal.gdal.Dataset-org.gdal.gdal.TranslateOptions-)

You can use translate function in two ways

```
public static Dataset Translate​(java.lang.String dest,
                            Dataset dataset,
                            TranslateOptions translateOptions,
                            ProgressCallback callback)
```

and

```
public static Dataset Translate​(java.lang.String dest,
                            Dataset dataset,
                            TranslateOptions translateOptions)
```

Comment: I have gone through this documentation but as a newbie to GDAL unable to figure out how to use it. An example will be great!!! @user4906240